# Entity Framework Return error - data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Document] @DetailID      INT=0,      
                                            @FKRegistrationID     INT,      
                                            @FKDocumentType       INT,      
                                            @License       VARCHAR(50)=NULL,      
                                            @FromDate     DATE=NULL,      
                                            @ExpiryDate DATE=NULL,      
                                            @FKConutryId          INT=NULL,      
                                            @StateId              INT=NULL     
AS      
     BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result INT=0;       
         IF(@DetailID = 0)      
             BEGIN      
                 INSERT INTO Detail      
                 (FKRegistrationID,      
                  FKDocumentType,      
                  License,      
                  FromDate,      
                  ExpiryDate,      
                  FKConutryId,      
                  FKStateId
                 )      
                 VALUES      
                 (@FKRegistrationID,      
                  @FKDocumentType,      
                  @License,      
                  @FromDate,    
                  @ExpiryDate,      
                  @FKConutryId,      
                  @StateId      
                 );

         END;      
             ELSE      
             BEGIN      
                 UPDATE Detail      
                   SET      
                       FKRegistrationID = @FKRegistrationID,      
                       FKDocumentType = @FKDocumentType,      
                       License = @License,      
                       FromDate = @FromDate,      
                       ExpiryDate = @ExpiryDate,      
                       FKConutryId = @FKConutryId,      
                       FKStateId = @StateId,      
                 WHERE DetailID = @DetailID;  
         END;      
     END;
```

`

Comment: Show the code where you call it. Off the top of my head, this is an INSERT and you are not returning a result.

Comment: @sfxwall Any progress?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the EF code that is calling this stored proc is expecting a result set to get returned.

Adding Select Scope_Identity() to the end of the insert block or Select 1 to the end of the update block should solve your problem.

Gary